# Join data.tables based on unequal timestamp

Tags: r, data.table

I am struggling with a problem related to merging two data.tables (although it could be data.frames as well) based on a timestamp (POSIXct) that is unequal.
Based on a certain timestamp in table *A* I'd like R to return me the entry in table *B* that occurs *prior* to the time in *A*.

**An example:**

I have **table A** that contains data about activities at a certain point in time.

**EDIT: This is different data to the original post that better reflects the problem: I need to 'lookup' based on timestamp and a grouping variable which I call Station ID. Apologies for not being clear in the first place.**.

```
             Start.Time Start.Station.ID
1: 2014-04-06 18:24:32              238
2: 2014-04-06 18:20:30              238
3: 2014-04-06 01:04:13              373
4: 2014-04-06 01:03:36              373
5: 2014-04-06 01:03:37              373
6: 2014-04-06 01:03:01              373
7: 2014-04-06 01:02:42              373
8: 2014-04-06 01:02:31              373
```

I want to add a column to that table A that indicates what the status for that station was at a certain point in time in terms of 'availability'. These status can be found in **table B**.

```
              status_dt station_id availability
 1: 2014-04-06 00:29:02        238    0.9354839
 2: 2014-04-06 00:29:02        373    1.0000000
 3: 2014-04-06 01:29:03        238    1.0000000
 4: 2014-04-06 01:29:03        373    0.6111111
 5: 2014-04-06 02:59:03        238    0.9354839
 6: 2014-04-06 02:59:03        373    0.6666667
    ...
41: 2014-04-06 17:59:03        238    0.8387097
42: 2014-04-06 17:59:03        373    0.4444444
43: 2014-04-06 18:59:03        238    0.9032258
44: 2014-04-06 18:59:03        373    0.5000000
45: 2014-04-06 20:29:03        238    0.7741935
              status_dt station_id availability
```

The timestamps do not match, therefore I'd like to add to table A the status from table B at the observation prior to timestamp in table A.

The *expected result* would be for example column 'availability':

```
             status_dt station_id availability 
1: 2014-04-06 18:24:32        238    0.8387097         
2: 2014-04-06 18:20:30        238    0.8387097            
3: 2014-04-06 01:04:13        373    1.0000000            
4: 2014-04-06 01:03:36        373    1.0000000           
5: 2014-04-06 01:03:37        373    1.0000000            
6: 2014-04-06 01:03:01        373    1.0000000          
7: 2014-04-06 01:02:42        373    1.0000000           
8: 2014-04-06 01:02:31        373    1.0000000
```

BodieG's proposal works if the entries in Start.Station.ID/station_id are unique, but applying his suggestion to this data gives

```
             status_dt station_id availability Start.Station.ID
1: 2014-04-06 18:24:32        373    0.4444444              238
2: 2014-04-06 18:20:30        373    0.4444444              238
3: 2014-04-06 01:04:13        373    1.0000000              373
4: 2014-04-06 01:03:36        373    1.0000000              373
5: 2014-04-06 01:03:37        373    1.0000000              373
6: 2014-04-06 01:03:01        373    1.0000000              373
7: 2014-04-06 01:02:42        373    1.0000000              373
8: 2014-04-06 01:02:31        373    1.0000000              373
```

Where the entries in the first two rows are not what I would have expected (or rather hoped for): they refer to the 'availability' in station 373 instead of 238.

I guess the code just has to be adapted to reflect the timestamp AND the station ID, but I'm banging my head against the wall here....
Also I could not figure out whether using the suggested xts-package would help, because clearly I have duplicated timesteps here...

Again, any hint is very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

**For reproducibility:**
Table A:

```
structure(list(Start.Time = structure(c(1396808672, 1396808430, 
1396746253, 1396746216, 1396746217, 1396746181, 1396746162, 1396746151
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Start.Station.ID = c(238, 
238, 373, 373, 373, 373, 373, 373)), .Names = c("Start.Time", 
"Start.Station.ID"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Table B:

```
   structure(list(status_dt = structure(c(1396744142, 1396744142, 
1396747743, 1396747743, 1396753143, 1396753143, 1396754942, 1396754942, 
1396756743, 1396756743, 1396758542, 1396758542, 1396760343, 1396760343, 
1396765743, 1396765743, 1396767542, 1396767542, 1396772943, 1396772943, 
1396778402, 1396778402, 1396781943, 1396781943, 1396785542, 1396785542, 
1396787342, 1396787342, 1396790942, 1396790942, 1396794543, 1396794543, 
1396798143, 1396798143, 1396799943, 1396799943, 1396801743, 1396801743, 
1396805343, 1396805343, 1396807143, 1396807143, 1396810743, 1396810743, 
1396816143, 1396816143, 1396817942, 1396817942, 1396821542, 1396821542, 
1396826942, 1396826942), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    station_id = c(238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 
    373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 
    373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 
    373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 
    373, 238, 373, 238, 373, 238, 373), availability = c(0.935483870967742, 
    1, 1, 0.611111111111111, 0.935483870967742, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.967741935483871, 0.666666666666667, 0.967741935483871, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.935483870967742, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.967741935483871, 0.666666666666667, 0.967741935483871, 
    0.611111111111111, 0.967741935483871, 0.611111111111111, 
    1, 0.444444444444444, 0.870967741935484, 0.5, 0.806451612903226, 
    0.5, 0.774193548387097, 0.388888888888889, 0.709677419354839, 
    0.388888888888889, 0.67741935483871, 0.333333333333333, 1, 
    0.5, 0.903225806451613, 0.444444444444444, 0.935483870967742, 
    0.444444444444444, 0.903225806451613, 0.444444444444444, 
    0.870967741935484, 0.444444444444444, 0.838709677419355, 
    0.444444444444444, 0.903225806451613, 0.5, 0.774193548387097, 
    0.611111111111111, 0.766666666666667, 0.611111111111111, 
    0.774193548387097, 0.555555555555556, 0.870967741935484, 
    0.666666666666667)), .Names = c("status_dt", "station_id", 
"availability"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-52L), sorted = "status_dt")
```

Comment: You can still use the solution from @BrodieG but matching by both `station_id` and the timestamp (in that order). That will guarantee a precise match by ID, but a rolling one for the time.

Comment: Thanks! Agreed, @BrodieG's still works. I do not know how to implement @ilir's suggestion. Instead I understood from [the data.table introduction](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-intro.pdf) that the join happens in a certain order, and therefore I re-ordered the columns in the data.table. That seems to do the trick:  `A2 <- A[,c(2,1)]` and `setkey(B, station_id, status_dt)`

Comment: You just have to set the keys differently: `setkey(A, Start.Station.ID, Start.Time)` and for B `setkey(B, station_id, status_dt)`. Then you run the same rolling join `B[A, roll=T]`

Comment: Thanks @ilir. That is much nicer than my approach. A lot to learn on my side when it comes to `data.table`.

Comment: My approach was the same as yours (setting a key essentially sorts the table). Deciding to switch to using `data.tables` was tricky at first, but the best decision I've made using R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `roll` parameter:

```
setkey(B, status_dt)
B[A, roll=TRUE]
```

Produces:

```
              status_dt station_id availability Start.Station.ID
 1: 2014-04-06 21:07:42        225    0.4864865              225
 2: 2014-04-06 21:06:50        225    0.4864865              225
 3: 2014-04-06 21:06:49        225    0.4864865              225
 4: 2014-04-06 21:06:15        225    0.4864865              225
 5: 2014-04-06 21:04:35        225    0.4864865              225
 6: 2014-04-06 21:05:33        225    0.4864865              225
 7: 2014-04-06 21:04:45        225    0.4864865              225
 8: 2014-04-06 21:04:37        225    0.4864865              225
 9: 2014-04-06 21:04:35        225    0.4864865              225
10: 2014-04-06 21:01:45        225    0.4864865              225
11: 2014-04-06 21:00:57        225    0.4864865              225
12: 2014-04-06 20:59:04        225    0.4864865              225
13: 2014-04-06 20:58:04        225    0.8648649              225
14: 2014-04-06 20:57:22        225    0.8648649              225
15: 2014-04-06 20:57:24        225    0.8648649              225
16: 2014-04-06 20:56:40        225    0.8648649              225
17: 2014-04-06 20:55:52        225    0.8648649              225
18: 2014-04-06 20:55:25        225    0.8648649              225
19: 2014-04-06 20:55:24        225    0.8648649              225
20: 2014-04-06 20:55:00        225    0.8648649              225
21: 2014-04-06 18:25:30        225    0.9729730              225
22: 2014-04-06 18:25:28        225    0.9729730              225
              status_dt station_id availability Start.Station.ID
```

This matches closely to your expected output, except it has some extra rows that as far as I can tell are legitimate per your description of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly use the [zoo](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=zoo) or [xts](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=xts) packages which were essentially written for this.

```
R> dfA <- as.data.frame(A)
R> a <- xts(dfA[,2], order.by=dfA[,1])
R> dfB <- as.data.frame(B)
R> b <- xts(dfB[,-1], order.by=dfB[,1])
```

Now that we have two  [xts](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=xts)  object, we can just `merge()` and run `na.locf()` over the result to fill `NA` with prior values:

```
R> na.locf(merge(a, b))
                      a station_id availability
2014-04-06 17:59:03  NA        225     0.972973
2014-04-06 18:25:28 225        225     0.972973
2014-04-06 18:25:30 225        225     0.972973
2014-04-06 18:59:03 225        225     0.621622
2014-04-06 20:29:03 225        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:55:00 225        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:55:24 225        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:55:25 225        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:55:52 225        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:56:40 225        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:57:22 225        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:57:24 225        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:58:04 225        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:59:02 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 20:59:04 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:00:57 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:01:45 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:04:35 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:04:35 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:04:37 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:04:45 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:05:33 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:06:15 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:06:49 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:06:50 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:07:42 225        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:59:02 225        225     0.162162
2014-04-06 23:29:02 225        225     0.162162
R>
```

But there ought to be a [data.table](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=data.table) answer in this too...

*Edit:* Per the comment, here is merge with just `a` timestamps:

```
R> na.locf(merge(a, b))[index(a), -1]
                    station_id availability
2014-04-06 18:25:28        225     0.972973
2014-04-06 18:25:30        225     0.972973
2014-04-06 20:55:00        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:55:24        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:55:25        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:55:52        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:56:40        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:57:22        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:57:24        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:58:04        225     0.864865
2014-04-06 20:59:04        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:00:57        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:01:45        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:04:35        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:04:35        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:04:37        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:04:45        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:05:33        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:06:15        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:06:49        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:06:50        225     0.486486
2014-04-06 21:07:42        225     0.486486
R>
```

In this particular case I also removed the redundant station id column.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hadn't thought about xts, so this is a great hint. However, the expected output would NOT contain data from B; thus the entry at 18:59:03 should not appear in the output. I tried `na.locf(merge(a, coredata(b))` following a discussion [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Combining-XTS-objects-with-unmatched-but-regular-dates-td2329335.html), but that did not work. Overall @BrodieG 's answer seems to solve my case here. Thanks to you both or that quick support!

Comment: I see. In that case one way to achieve this is to re-index by `a`. See my updated answer.